# fullpage.js dynamically added sections: how to scroll inside the sections

Tags: fullpage.js

I am adding the sections in HTML using JS from this object:

```
var slidesArray = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'title': '1 title',
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'title': '2 title',
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'title': '3 title',
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'title': '4 title',
        }
    ];
```

like this:

```
var $container = $('#fullpage'),
    shuffledItems = "",
    shuffledItemsTemplate =
                "<div class='section fp-scrollable'>" +
                    "<div class='section_title'>{TITLE}</div>" +
                "</div>";

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       shuffledItems = shuffledItemsTemplate.replace(/{TITLE}/g, slidesArray[i]["title"]);

       $container.append(shuffledItems);
    }
```

which results in the following HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage" class="sections">
    <div class="section fp-scrollable">
      <div class="section_title">1 title</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section fp-scrollable">
      <div class="section_title">2 title</div>
    </div>

    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Simple enough.

Here's the fullpage configuration:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
                css3: true,
                scrollingSpeed: 1000,
                navigation: true,
                slidesNavigation: true,
                controlArrows: false,
                scrollOverflow: true, // even though this is set to true, it's not working
                scrollOverflowOptions: {
                    scrollbars: false,
                },
            });
```

My problem is that I cannot scroll inside any div that's scrollable and is inside `<div class="section"></div>`, even though `scrollOverflow: true` is set, and I added the files in the correct order in the HTML. Any idea what might cause this issue and how to solve it?

```
<script src="Scripts/Legacy/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Legacy/third-party/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Legacy/third-party/fullpage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the method `fullpage_api.reBuid()` right after appending a section. Try it out.

That, or initialise fullPage.js after appending the contents.

In any case, fullPage.js won't be able to detect new sections appended dynamically, you would have to put some more work from your part to make it work. Namely, destroying fullPage.js and initialising it again with every section/slide you add/remove dynamically.

Comment: fullPage.js does initialise after appending the content. I've tried some changes and I think it had something to do with my styling. Now the problem I have is that I cannot scroll with the mousewheel to the bottom of the section. What happens is that I can only scroll about 80% down the section and then it automatically goes to the next section. It never lets me reach the end. If I drag the bar  with my mouse, I can reach the bottom of the section, and that seems to be the only way.